# Как лучше хранить entity?

Tags: javascript, typescript

В общем первый подход был такой

```
public entities: Entities.GameEntity[] = [];
public players: Entities.PlayerEntity[] = [];
```

Когда мне нужно найти entity делаю так

```
public findPlayer(playerId: string) {

    let playerFounded: Entities.PlayerEntity = null;
    this.players.forEach((player: Entities.PlayerEntity)=> {
        if (player.client.socketId == playerId) {
            playerFounded = player;
        }
    });

    return playerFounded;
}
```

Второй подход был такой

```
public entities: any = {};
public ids: number[] = [];
```

Добавление

```
entityParams[0] - id of number

this.entities[entityParams[0]] = entity;
this.ids.push(Number(entityParams[0]));
```

Обход всех

```
this.ids.forEach((entityId)=> {
   this.entities[entityId] 
});
```

ну и если нужно быстро достать то `this.entities[entityId]`

Как можно более лучше делать такие вещи, и какой из этих подходов лучше

Comment: все зависит от задачи: если будут применяться фильтры - то оба способы не очень при большом количестве данных

Comment: а Вы можете конкретней сказать что Вы хотите хранить? Просто не зная какой подход для разработки Вы выбрали и под какую технологию пишите, сложно что-то конкретное посоветовать. Мне даже кажется странным, что Вам вообще что-то советую :)

Answer (score 2):

Подобную задачу решал создавая специальный класс коллекцию `Collection`

Вспомогательный интерфейс `IKey`

```
interface IKey {
   key: string;
}
```

Интерфейс коллекции

```
interface ICollection<T extends IKey> {
    add(value: T);
    get(key: string): T;
    remove(key: string);
}
```

И сама реализация. Индекс элемента в массиве храним в хэше, поэтому не нужно делать полный перебор массива.

```
class Collection<T extends IKey> implements ICollection<T> {

    private array: T[] = [];
    private keyToIndex: {[key: string]: number} = {};

    add(value: T) {
        this.array.push(value);
        this.keyToIndex[value.key] = this.array.length - 1;
    }

    get(key: string): T {
        return this.array[this.keyToIndex[key]];
    }

    remove(key: string) {
        this.array.splice(this.keyToIndex[key], 1);
        delete this.keyToIndex[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: вот это мне больше нравится, лучше читается

Comment: но что если нужен будет индекс ещё по имени, а понял, я просто добавлю  private keyToIndex: {[key: string]: number} = {};

Answer (score 1):

Если объем данных который будет храниться в массиве небольшой, то может выбирать любой вариант.

А вот если данных будет большие, то будут проблемы с производительностью. Я разрабатываю приложения для мобильных устройств (cordova), так вот там у меня возникли эти проблемы (массив был около 1500 элементов). И чтобы решить их мы придумали вот такую хитрость:

```js
// recordKeyName {string} первичный ключ
// record {any} элемент
// records {any[]} массив для обработки
setMapping: function (recordKeyName, record, records) {
        if (!records['maps']) {
            records['maps'] = {};
            records.getRecordByKey = function (link) {
                return records.maps[link];
            };
        }

        records['maps'][record[recordKeyName]] = record;
}
```

```js
// индексирование массива
for (var i = 0; i <= items.length - 1; i++) {
    this.setMapping('LINK', items[i], items);
}
```

В дополнение к этому мы еще индексируем дополнительные поля, чтобы фильтрация происходила быстрей (в примере этого нет)

В итоге получилось так, что при обычном просмотре массива время уходило примерно ~33 мс, а через индексы ~0,08

Comment: в чем смысл установки флага `records.isMaps = true;`?

Comment: он там не нужен, забыл убрать. Я его использовал чтобы определять поддерживает массив индексы или нет

Comment: заодно и _var me = this;_ тоже, все равно нигде не используется